# MS Access database unexpectedly large

Tags: database, ms-access, size

I am  learning with and at the same time trying to put together a small application in MS Access (pls don't judge:)) and all they .accdb files I produced are inordinately large in comparison to their contents.

E.g. I have on database with 4 tables, each with about 20 entries and 2-4 columns for each; 1 table with 1500 entries with 5 columns; 1 query between two smaller tables and on form with 4 cascaded comboboxes. There are no pictures and the data in the tables is only short integers and short texts not exceeding 40 characters (most of the time much less). This .accdb file has 14 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access databases tend to cache A LOT on disk, and tend to not clear the cache very often.

If size is a problem, I'd turn on the *compact on close* option. I've had databases with sizes over 100MB that didn't contain any actual data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Compact & Repair" in File->Info menu to reduce size of your .accdb files.